# How to get the windows clipboard content and use it in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a simple windows form application which has a button and text box. How do I automatically paste the path that I just copied from windows explorer or any other program to the text box when I load the form, so that I don't have to paste the copied path to the text box?

Answer (score 2):

Clipboard is inside System.Windows.Forms, use this way:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
{
    var filesArray = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
}
else if(Clipboard.ContainsText())
{
    var fileName = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to paste the file path when you copy a path during form load then try

```
if(Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                var fileName = Clipboard.GetText();
                textBox1.Text=fileName;
            }
```